# transition css top and bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make such animation ?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTWjH.png)
please check link below
https://preview.themeforest.net/item/shopify-outstock-clean-minimal-drag-drop/full_screen_preview/21041667?_ga=2.52492833.847676305.1666954417-2031082058.1666954417

```
.wrap-img {
transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease 0s;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
background: #fff;
padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be this:

```css
.box {
  /* Required for the position: absolute property of the overlay. */
  position: relative; 
}

/* Scroll up and down effect */
.scrolling {
  background-size: cover !important;
  width: 285px;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: 15px solid #fff;  /* Border is white */
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-position 1.5s ease-out 0.5s
}

.scroll {
  background: url("https://velatheme.com/demo/outstock/images/cosmetic2.jpg");
  background-position: top center;
}

.scroll_top:hover {
  background-position: bottom center !important;
  transition: background-position 2s linear 0s;
}

/* Background separating the image and the button */

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Button */

button {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 158px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
}

.box button:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="box scrolling scroll scroll_top">
  <div class="overlay">
    <button>VIEW DEMO</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

To do the opposite effect, you would first have to change the classes to scroll_bottom and it would just change:

In .scroll :

```
background-position: bottom center;
```

And in .scroll_top:hover (In this case it would be .scroll_bottom:hover):

```
background-position: top center !important;
```